# Possible Issues with battery Powered sensor and collector star network

Tags: wireless

I am designing a wireless Sub-Ghz network consist of many battery powered sensor nodes with a single collector node.

For lowest power possible, the sensor stays most of the time in sleep mode waking up periodically to send out data.

Possible problems I can think of are as follows

1) Since the network must agree on which band to use, is there any protocol to prevent collision when two or more nodes transmit at the same time including not just within the network, but also including interference from outside of the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched few more days, and found that there is an idea called CSMA/CA.

Could find many lectures on Youtube.